# Как сделать так, чтобы пробелы заменялись тире?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Как сделать так, чтобы вместо % ставилось - ?

пример кода
**PHP**

```
<?php
$animename = 'no game no life'; 
$animeID = '6'; ?>
<div class='content-img-block'>
        <img src='https://chitoge.sovetromantica.com/anime/<?php echo $animeID?>_<?php echo $animename?>/images/<?php echo $animeID?>.jpg'>
    </div>
```

Как результат - https://chitoge.sovetromantica.com/anime/6_no%game%no%life/images/6.jpg ;
А нужно - https://chitoge.sovetromantica.com/anime/6_no-game-no-life/images/6.jpg ;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По идее можно через `str_replace`

```
<img src='https://chitoge.sovetromantica.com/anime/<?php echo $animeID?>_<?php echo str_replace(' ', '-', $animename) ?>/images/<?php echo $animeID?>.jpg'>
```

ещё лучше наверное `preg_replace`, т.е. замена по регулярному выражению

```
<img src='https://chitoge.sovetromantica.com/anime/<?php echo $animeID?>_<?php echo preg_replace('/(\s+)/i', '-', $animename) ?>/images/<?php echo $animeID?>.jpg'>
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!

Comment: на самом деле /[^a-z0-9]+/i, ну и транслит